# Same functions in different views - Django

Tags: django

I have started learning Django recently and am following the code examples given in the tutorial of the Django site. Accordingly, I have created a site 'mysite' and an app 'books' in that site. Consequently, there are two 'views.py' files in the resultant directory structure - one in the 'mysite' folder and one in 'books' folder and there's only one 'urls.py' file - in the 'mysite' folder only. My question is the following - how do I avoid name conflicts for the functions that I create in the two 'views.py' files? If there are two functions with the same name in both the files, how does Django resolve which function to call for a given URL pattern in 'urls.py' file?

The following is my directory structure:

```
C:.
│   manage.py
│
├───books
│       admin.py
│       admin.pyc
│       models.py
│       models.pyc
│       tests.py
│       views.py
│       views.pyc
│       __init__.py
│       __init__.pyc
│
└───mysite
        base.html
        base_blog.html
        base_welcome.html
        currdate.html
        settings.py
        settings.pyc
        urls.py
        urls.pyc
        views.py
        views.pyc
        wsgi.py
        wsgi.pyc
        __init__.py
        __init__.pyc
```

An additional and related question - if I have multiple projects (like 'mysite') and different apps in those projects, how do I differentiate the URLs across the projects? I mean, currently, the URL `http://127.0.0.1:8000/hello` is mapped to a view function in 'mysite' project. What if I now have one more project, say 'mynewsite', how would Django resolve the URL `http://127.0.0.1:8000/hello` to the view function of 'mynewsite'? I hope my question is clear.

Thanks,
Rakesh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python you can import libraries (in this case file like views.py) one of them would be causing name conflicts you are talking about, namely

```
from books.views import my_view
from mysite.views import my_view
```

in that case, my_view will simply be overwritten. However, you can also do the following

```
import books.views
import mysite.views
```

In that case, to access the imported view, you will have to use full path, i. e. books.views.my_view, therefore there is no name conflict.

As for your other question, consider the following urls.py contents:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', mysite.views.my_view, name='index'),
```

You can replace it with

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', books.views.my_view, name='index'),
```

Comment: Thank you @lisu, that solved my issue. But I have added a related question to my original post. Can you please help me clarify that?

Comment: Well, my confusion is the following - is it that when I create a project using 'django-admin.py startproject mysite' command, does django use the localhost:8000 URL only for the views/templates/files from this project? Can I create a new project using the same command and still use the same localhost:8000 URL to access the views from my new project?

Comment: @Rakesh K When you create a project, you're probably running django dev server, using runserver.py. This server handles all requests to 127.0.0.1:8000 and yes, it will always point to your project. However, if you create another one, you can just change the port on which the runserver runs (see runserver.py --help) to 8080 and you're good to run two projects at the same time. If you don't change port, you will not be able to run two servers at once.