# Error with two same views in different apps in django project

Tags: python, django

Working on django project. There are two apps in my project one is custom defined "admin", and another is "home". I am using some views same in both app for eg:- My admin app urls.py file is

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^logout$', views.logout, name='logout'),
    url(r'^dashboard$', views.dashboard, name='dashboard'),
    url(r'^profile$', views.profile, name='profile'),
    url(r'^edit-profile$', views.edit_profile, name='edit-profile'),
    url(r'^check-password$', views.check_password, name='check-password'),
    url(r'^testing$', views.testing_database, name='testing'),
]
```

and my home's app urls.py file is:-

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^sport$', views.sport, name='sport'),
    url(r'^register$', views.signup_signin, name='register'),
    url(r'^logout$', views.logout_view, name='logout'),
    url(r'^dashboard$', views.dashboard, name='dashboard'),
    url(r'^create-new-event$', views.create_new_event, name='create-new-event')
]
```

So you can check that some views are same in both of views.py file, That why whenever I am trying to login into the admin panel it's redirectingme to the home app's dashboard, and when I try to logout from admin panel it's redirecting me on home's app index page. I think that this is the problem of same views in both apps. I also tried to import views of particular app in respective urls.py file. for example:-

```
from home import views
```

in home's urls.py file and for admin

```
from admin import views
```

but its giving me error:-

```
from admin import views
ImportError: cannot import name views
```

my root urls.py file is :-

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include('admin.urls')),
    url(r'^home/', include('home.urls')),
]
```

I also checked this solution on stackoverflow but did not get solution

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26083515/same-functions-in-different-views-django
```

Comment: I just changed the order of url patterns in my root urls.py file and found that my admin login is working fine, but after this home app login is giving error and redirected me on admin dashboard. Means problem is in this file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so Django has something to solve this problem of yours.

What you can do is specify the `namespace` for the urls in your root **urls.py** and then when using then you can use this `namespace` value while **reversing the url** in your **html templates** when you specify the urls to redirect to.

Something like this:

**root urls.py** will look pretty much the same as yours, just add the `namespace` value to the `home.urls` like this:

```
url(r'^admin/', include('admin.urls', namespace='home')),
```

So now whenever you will be using the **home** app urls, then you can do something like this for redirecting:

```
<a href="{% url "home:logout" %}> Logout </a>
```

So now when you click on this `<a>` tag of **Logout**, then it will look for the **home** namespace and hence will pick the url whose `name` is `logout` from the **home** app and not from the **admin** app irrespective of the order in which you have included the urls in your root url.py

There are other solutions too which will require changing your URL patterns.
Like, either you can change the original url value or you can have different `name` value of same urls in different apps, but then when Django is already providing you the flexibility to do what you want to by using the power of `namespace`.

See this -> https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/urls/#url-namespaces-and-included-urlconfs

I hope the above will resolve your issue.

Comment: Happy to help. :)

Answer (score 0):

The `admin` in your root urls.py specifies the django admin module, and not your custom application. You have not included your admin app's urls in the root url at all.

Comment: But i have included admin same as home

Comment: @PankajSharma admin basically means the django's default admin app. So including admin includes the default admin app and not your custom app

Comment: So should I change my complete admin app ? or is there any alternate for this ?

Comment: @PankajSharma The easiest way is to change your app name